# How does Grand Central Dispatch work?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management

I am a beginner programmer.

How do you use GCD in a swift app? I assume you use this only for larger projects where memory management is important? Do you use it in a way in which you "categorize" the major blocks of execution and then assign them priorities (if it's async)?

Is it only the global and main background queues that exist, or there are more? How do they relate to *threads*?

If someone could give me specific examples of how the above is used, that would be great.

Comment: "I assume you use this only for larger projects where memory management is important?" You assume wrong. It has nothing to do with memory management. It has to do with threading. — I doubt this will do any good, since you seem unwilling to do any learning / thinking / reading on your own (otherwise you wouldn't be on Stack Overflow asking for this entire subject to be handed to you on a silver platter), but I have written a book with a Threading chapter that develops this subject with some cogency, and you can read it online: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html

Comment: Thank you! Buying your book soon, great content you have